# Ubuntu (22.04) white screen flickering when doing install from thumbdrive. When installed in safe graphics mode, and on log in, screen is blank white

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia, graphics

## Installation

As in the title - when I insert my thumbdrive (containing a freshly downloaded ubuntu ISO) to boot in and to try to install, the screen constantly flickers. This is in **non-dual boot**

I instead tried to boot into safe graphics mode, which completely addressed the flickering. During the installation process, I'm prompted to install third party drivers and I've tried both installing and not installing. This leads to the next part....

### Logging in

In both cases, where I've installed the 3rd party drivers and not-installed them, when I log in (the login screen works fine), I then get a blank white screen. Interestingly, my mouse can be seen and can be moved.

---

Edit: I completely removed the GPU unit, and hte problem persisted (flickering when booting from a live USB to do the install) so I doubt that this is the issue.

Perhaps the issue is with my GPU? I've got an Nvidia 4080 if that helps at all(?). I think that it is installed correctly - the lights are on and the fans are spinning. Any thoughts and ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation is to use the "native" NVIDIA driver, which can be obtained on Ubuntu via the Hardware tab - you've seemed to do everything right!

Since Nvidia does not support Wayland, you should log in with the X Server Session after your (renewed)installation. (Check the little "cog" icon on the right side of your Login Screen)

Comment: Gotcha! So, would you recommend installing via safe-mode, not pre-installing the third-party graphics and when I log in I use xorg (ubuntu on xorg?) Because I still get the white screen :( It seems like the white screen pops up regardless of whether the GPU is connected to the desktop or not. I've also verified the ubuntu install if that helps

Comment: The issue was my stupid monitor cable was loose. I must have knocked it loose when I was changing OSs or something. I'm just gonna mark your solution as the right one (you were definitely right)